# How to acces baker adres (bip25519) on tezbox

Tags: ledger, tezbox

When I open my ledger on tezbox, it automatically opens the ed25519 address. Is there a way to change the derivation path that you want to access?

Comment: Tezbox is no longer a supported web wallet. You should switch to Galleon, Ledger Live, Magnum, Atomic Wallet, Trust Wallet, etc.

Comment: I run info the same problem with all the other wallets. Point is they all open the ed25519 adres (44'/1729'/0'/0') but my Baker is using the bip25519 adres, and i can't figure out how to open that with these Wallers.

Comment: @LucGoldman use another wallet

Comment: @LucGoldman There's always the official tezos cli. You can access bip25519 addresses with the command "./tezos-client import secret key new uri", where uri is like ledger://<animals>/bip25519[/<path>]
https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html#client-manual

Comment: @steakandbake Thank you very much. I will try that option, unfortunately i'm not that familair with using the tezos-client. Therefore i was wondering if there is an online wallet that opens the other curves like bip. Apparently there is not one i guess.